# Get only non empty fields from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a long table and I need to display column names and their respective values only if its not null.
So, here is what I came up with as a concept but the implementation doesn't work.

```
$sql = "Select * from audittable where id = " . $id;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


$sqlfields = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM audittable where field not in ("audit_id","last_by","last_datetime","id")';
$fieldsquery = mysql_query($sqlfields);

echo "<table style='width:100%;padding:8px'>
    <tr class='heading'><td>Field Name</td><td>Value</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    foreach ($rowfields = mysql_fetch_array($fieldsquery)) {
        if ($rowfields["field"] == $row[0] && $row[0]!=""){
   ?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
    <td><?=$row[1]?></td>

</tr>
<?php
        }
    }   
}
echo "</table>";
```

I'm not sure the logic is right (two loops), any ideas ?

Maybe I wasnt clear enough, the table includes 50 fields, most probably 3 or 4 of them will have a value per row, I need to display only those columns that has values

Thanks

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Check is null

`$sql = "Select * from audittable where id = " . $id." AND YOUR_FIELD_NAME IS NOT NULL";`

Comment: what does NAME represent here ?

Comment: Field name which you want to use

Comment: So the problem with this solution is that the logic would be completely different if you were to use it because there are an enumerable number of fields in which `NULL` needs to be checked against. So, for this idea to work, this statement would need run for every single column, thus implying 50+ round trips to the database. Probably not a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Apart of checking it is NULL, I usually check if it is not set as empty.

```
SELECT * from audittable where id = " . $id." AND (NAME IS NOT NULL OR NAME != '' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is sound actually, but the problem I see is that you're not actually checking against the field **or** for `null` here:

```
if ($rowfields["field"] == $row[0] && $row[0] != "")
```

so I think you have a couple options. First, you could do this:

```
if ($row[$rowfields["field"]] != null
    && $row[$rowfields["field"]] != "")
```

**or** you could do this:

```
if (!empty($row[$rowfields["field"]]))
```

however, there is a caveat with `empty`. The PHP manual says:

```
The following things are considered to be empty: 
  * "" (an empty string)
  * 0 (0 as an integer)
  * 0.0 (0 as a float)
  * "0" (0 as a string)
  * NULL
  * FALSE
  * array() (an empty array)
  * $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

so if you have any `integer` or `float` fields that would be `0` **but** you don't consider those `empty` this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from audittable where id = " . $id." AND (NAME IS NOT NULL OR NAME > "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to print out only fieldname and result of the columns that have some values:

```
/* fetch associative array */
   $i=1;
   while($a = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $i++;
     foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
     if($value != NULL) {
        echo $key." = ".$value."<br/>";
        }
     }
     echo "-- <br />";    
   } 
   ...
```